# Format a large amount of dates

Tags: gedcom, gramps, date

I recently got access to some of my grandpas genealogy research, which I have imported to Gramps as a ".ged"-file. Many of the dates are in a format which Gramps doesn't understand: [image: Data formating]

Is there anyway to reformat all of my dates at the same time, instead of going through them one by one?

Answer (score 7):

A GEDCOM file is a text file. You can open it up in a text editor and do "search and replace".

I would suggest 12 different replacements; one for each month.
For example, replace `" juni "` with `" jun "`. (include the spaces so you don't mess up other bits of the file).

Of course, you'll want to do this on a copy of the GEDCOM file; not the original.

Comment: Yeah, definitely include the spaces, else you'll be renaming all of your relatives with Julia-type names. :-)

Comment: That would work! Now I only have the problem that some dates are in a "day-month-year"-format. I can only get Gramps to register dates if they are as "year-month-day".

Answer (score 3):

This is intended to be a supplement to the [earlier answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/18496/1006) for users who need a bit more information about editing text files.

I'll start by repeating the excellent advice which was given already.

1. **ALWAYS** work on a **copy** of your GEDCOM file and not the original!
2. When you do a search and replace, include the spaces on either side of the month names, so you won't edit any instances in those strings in the middle of words.

A GEDCOM is a text file which can be edited with a [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor).  These programs are sometimes called *plain text editors* to distinguish them from programs that use *[rich text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)* such as Microsoft Word and other word processors.

Wikipedia's articles [List of Text Editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors) and [Comparison of text editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) contain more information about available editors and their features.

Some editors such as [TextPad editor](https://www.textpad.com/home) have add-ons that will allow them to be used with GEDCOM; see the help for information about the TextPad GEDCOM syntax file.

For a comprehensive list of GEDCOM utilities such as GEDCOM validators, see Cyndi's List: [Category GEDCOM software and tools](https://www.cyndislist.com/gedcom/gedcom-software/).

Resources:

Family Historian User Group Knowledge Base articles

- [Using a Text Editor with GEDCOM files](https://fhug.org.uk/kb/kb-article/using-a-text-editor-with-gedcom-files/)
- GEDCOM tools: [GedPad Editor](https://fhug.org.uk/kb/link/gedpad-editor-3/)
- GEDCOM tools: [PSPad Editor](https://fhug.org.uk/kb/link/pspad-editor-3/)

ThoughtCo article: [How to Read and Open a GEDCOM file](https://www.thoughtco.com/genealogy-gedcom-basics-1421891)